# Datatable plugin enable for all features

Tags: jquery, datatable

I would like to create a client side datatable. It will support pagination, sorting for unicode(especially Japanese language), row merge(row span for data row) and column fixed for data row. And then it will run on IE 8-11, Firefox, Chrome and Safari of Ipad.

When I have tested with Jquery datatable(http://datatable.net/), it cannot support row merge.

I just want to know which datatable plugin can support for there all features.

For row merge, please see table example

```
_______________________________________________
|       |__________|           |_______________|
|       |__________|           |_______________|
|_______|__________|___________|_______________|
|       |__________|           |_______________|
|       |__________|           |_______________|
|_______|__________|___________|_______________|
|       |__________|           |_______________|
|       |__________|           |_______________|
|_______|__________|___________|_______________|
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm....not sure on exactly what you are looking for but from what I am seeing this is all covered under the datatables plug-in.  The great thing about datatables is there are also plugins for it.   In this case there is one for row merges.

See if this gets you where you are looking to go

[DataTables Row Grouping Add-on](http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html)

Comment: I don't want to get row grouping. I just want to get row merge or row span within datatable. The Jquery datatable dose not support it. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204252/jquery-datatable-row-grouping.